# Issue on AngularJs and ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to created a tabulator using `AngularJS`. The 2 static tabs are only as test pourpose, the idea is to have a list of objects and created the tabs dynamically. Here the code:

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-app="app" style="background-color: #f4f4f4">
  <table class="tabs-container" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: separate" ng-init="sss = '0'">
    <tr>
      <td class="tab" ng-click="sss = '0'" ng-class="{'sub-tab-active': sss  === '0'}">Test</td>
      <td class="tab" ng-click="sss = '00'" ng-class="{'sub-tab-active': sss  === '00'}">Test 00</td>
      <td class="tab" ng-click="sss = '000'" ng-class="{'sub-tab-active': sss  === '000'}">Test 000</td>
      <td class="tab" ng-repeat="b in beteiligungen" ng-click="sss = b.Key" ng-class="{'sub-tab-active': sss  === b.Key}">Test {{b.Key}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="container-full-border container-padding">
    <div ng-show="sss  === '0'">Test 0</div>
    <div ng-show="sss  === '00'">Test 00</div>
    <div ng-show="sss  === '000'">Test 000</div>
    <div ng-show="sss  === '0000'">Test 0000</div>
    <div ng-show="sss  === '00000'">Test 00000</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.beteiligungen = [{
    Key: "0000",
    Value: "Test1"

  }, {
    Key: "00000",
    Value: "Test2"
  }]
}]);
```

It is also on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vtyNaZQ0ta8IEvfovyW2?p=preview)

I don't understand why the class `sub-tab-active` is set but not unset once another tab is clicked.

Why do the static tabs work and the dynamic ones do not?

Comment: (additionally) if you have multiple `ng-if` used, you should try to replace them with `ng-switch="sss"`, so you can check with `ng-switch-when="0"`

Comment: Tanks for the hint, but in this sample sss is static. In the real context sss is dynamic, so I can't use the `ngSwitch`.

Comment: here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L6xOZEVwkVQ74vuVerln?p=preview) with an example, just for reference (might be useful)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `ng-click="sss = b.Key"` to `ng-click="$parent.sss = b.Key"`.

Directive `ng-repeat` creates a new child scope.

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat is creating a separate scope for every item.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat